# Pull data in columns according to a certain cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas, vba

https://www.dropbox.com/s/zag18z5f13fugn3/Coverlog%20Rota.xlsm?dl=0

Hi

Just need a bit of assistance. Tried a few ways of doing this but can't seem to get it to work.

Below is the Forumlae I used:

Fair enough. Below is my Formulae that I've used.

```
=INDEX('Cover LOG'!$E$1:$AR$89,MATCH(A3,'Cover LOG'!$C:$C,0),MATCH($B$1,'Cover LOG'!$E$1:$AR$1,0)*2)
```

It works with the first date, but when it gets to the second date the last four columns give back **#REF!**.

When it goes to the third date the last six columns this time bring back **#XREF!**.

[image: Sample of error]

I've uploaded the file on the link as this was the only way I could explain it fully.

Essentially when the date changes at the top on the **FC Dash** I want the relevant columns from **Cover LOG** to pull through.

Can anyone help?

Jay

Comment: ① This sounds like a "*here is my code … please fix it*". ② "*doesn't want to work*" is no meaningful error description. Are there any error messages, which and where? Also please add the **relevant code part** into your original question or build a [mcve]. It's very unlikely that people will download and execute macro enabled files (also they are likely to disappear after a while and the question gets useless for future readers). Possibly a screenshot can help too to explain your issue. You might want to read [ask] too.

Comment: Fair enough. Below is my Formulae that I've used. 

=INDEX('Cover LOG'!$E$1:$AR$89,MATCH(A3,'Cover LOG'!$C:$C,0),MATCH($B$1,'Cover LOG'!$E$1:$AR$1,0)*2)

It works with the first date, but when it gets to the second date the last four columns give back #REF!.

When it goes to the third date the last six columns this time bring back #XREF!.

Comment: Sorry, thank you! Edited the original question. I pressed save before I actually wrote the rest of the text, apologies.

Comment: So do you have issues with VBA or a formula now? Your question is very unclear. We even don't know how your data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably that one of the `Match` functions don't match and therefore the `Index` function fails. Or that the column/row exceeds the given range in the `Index` function.

So you need to evaluate your formula step-by-step:

1. Select the cell that you want to evaluate. Only one cell can be evaluated at a time.
2. On the **Formulas** tab, in the **Formula Auditing** group, click **Evaluate Formula**.
3. Click **Evaluate** to examine the value of the underlined reference. The result of the evaluation is shown in italics.

   If the underlined part of the formula is a reference to another formula, click **Step In** to display the other formula in the **Evaluation** box. Click **Step Out** to go back to the previous cell and formula.
4. Continue until each part of the formula has been evaluated.

More Info: [Evaluate a nested formula one step at a time](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/evaluate-a-nested-formula-one-step-at-a-time-59a201ae-d1dc-4b15-8586-a70aa409b8a7).

With a evaluation you see which part of your function returns which value. So you can easily see which `Match` function returns a value and which one fails because of no match.

---

Explanation of your debug result:

```
=INDEX('CoverLOG'!$e$1:$AR$89,3,68)
```

The above `Index` formula means get `row 3` and `column 68` of range `$e$1:$AR$89` in sheet `CoverLOG`.

If we now analyze the range `$e$1:$AR$89` it has `89 rows` and `40 columns`. You can test this with the following formulas:

```
=ROWS($E$1:$AR$89)    '=89
=COLUMNS($E$1:$AR$89) '=40
```

but you try to access `column 68` which exceeds the range total columns that is only `40 columns`.

Comment: I've done that.
I get:
`INDEX('CoverLOG'!$e$1:$AR$89,3,17*4)`

Then


`INDEX('CoverLOG'!$e$1:$AR$89,3,68)`

Then it fails. (#XREF!)

The only issue why I can't find the problem is why it happens when the date changes, and more columns get #xrefed. If it all failed at once I could understand it but...it only happens as the date at the top changes and it has to fetch the data further along the columns.

Comment: @Jaejay I added an explanation of your result: You exceed the total column count of your given range.

Comment: Thank you

That makes sense. I can see why its doing that but can't see how to fix it. So I suppose that isn't possible.

Is it possible to have a macro that returns a certain set of columns dependent on a cell value? That will probably be the way forward then, if so I'll go and have a bit of research and see what I can do.

Comment: That's probably too broad to be answered here, but should be possible with VBA. So do some research, and if you got stuck post a new question specifying which error you get or where you got stuck. It's obviously that calculating the column `17*4` is wrong and should be changed, so that should not be to hard to figure out for you how to calculate that correctly. Note that column 1 of  range `$e$1:$AR$89` is `E` not `A`! Column counting is relative to the starting point of the range no absolute counting of the sheet. This might help to know.